# Create a control after selecting Item from grid in MVVM

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, mvvm-light

I have a collection of items in grid(of telerik) and after I select any item of collection of items ( I know how to notice changing of selected item) I need to create a control in the same user control which will display some property of selected item.

The problem is that depending of what type(the class of collection have a field SomeType) of selected item is, I need to add a specific class.

So for example if I had a collection of cars, and I selected car which was suv, than I would had to add SuvControl, and when I selected van, then I would had to add VanControl. Those controls are different because have different names of fields and would have different behaviors.

I'm using MVVM Light .

I couldn't find any good example so I'll reward even for a link to some example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do would be binding the SelectedItem [property of the ListBox to the view model

```
SelectedItem={Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}
```

or you could do ElementName binding too - all this to get to the details view's viewmodel.

The details view would use a [DataTemplateSelector](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/52595#1024547) and you would display your details view like this:

```
<Grid
    x:Name="DetailsGrid">
    <prismvm:DataTemplateSelector
        Content={Binding SelectedItem}>
        <prismvm:DataTemplateSelector.Resources>
            <DataTemplate
                x:Key="Type1ViewModel">
                <views:Type1View/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate
                x:Key="Type2ViewModel">
                <views:Type2View/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </prismvm:DataTemplateSelector.Resources>
    </prismvm:DataTemplateSelector>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested the `DataTemplateSelector` is the right way to go in most cases, and certainly the cleanest.

An alternative when you have few different templates (2 or 3) if to put them all and bind their visibility to the item type property so only one is visible at a time. Again, this is nor the recommended technique but in simple cases it can bring you to the desired result quickly.